Logitstic regression varies among statsmodels GLM, statsmodels Logit, and skylearn LogisticRegression functions
All,
I found that the logistic regression of simple binary data varies greatly among the following functions.

statsmodels.api.GLM
statsmodels.api.Logit
sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression


The statsmodels.api.GLM fits the data exactly, and it seems to me sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression is better than statsmodels.api.Logit.
The figure above indicates that the solution varies among different functions, which might not be the case with the exponential of the log odd (odd) as follows:

statsmodels.api.GLM 1.2
sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression 1.1
statsmodels.api.Logit 1.03

Any idea why do those function varies?
Thanks
Here is the code

from scipy.special import expit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
import statsmodels.api as sm


x_glm=np.arange(50)
x=x_glm.reshape(-1,1)

x_with_ones=np.ones((len(x),2))
x_with_ones[:,1]=x_glm

y=np.ones(50)
y[:25]=0
y[20:24]=1
y[30:34]=0

#############Skylearn Logistic regression ######################
#############Skylearn Logistic regression ######################
model_logistic = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', random_state=0).fit(x, y)
sigmoid_auto=model_logistic.predict_proba(x)[:,1]
# sigmoid1=model_logistic.predict() # after apllying cutoff 0.5
print(model_logistic.intercept_)
print(model_logistic.coef_)

######### GLM logistic regresssion ###############
######### GLM logistic regresssion ###############
modelC         =sm.GLM(y,x_with_ones,family=sm.families.Binomial(link=sm.families.links.Logit())).fit()
sigmoid_glm=modelC.predict(x_with_ones)
# to get a list of the availabe link associted with specif family, print
print(sm.families.family.Binomial.links)
print(modelC.params)
######### sm.Logit regresssion ###############
######### sm.Logit regresssion ###############
model_logit = sm.Logit(y, x_with_ones).fit()
sigmoid_logit=model_logit.predict(x_with_ones)
print(model_logit.params)
print(model_logit.summary)

############## Figure ########################
############## Figure ########################
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x,y,facecolors='none', edgecolors='b',label='observations')
plt.scatter(x,sigmoid_auto,facecolors='none', edgecolors='g',label='sklearn LogisticRegression')
plt.scatter(x,sigmoid_glm,c='k',marker='+',
            label='sm.GLM')
plt.scatter(x,sigmoid_logit,marker='^',label='sm.Logit')

plt.legend( fontsize="20")

#%%  Interpretation 
# coef
#  sm.GLM
print(np.exp(modelC.params[3]))
# Skylearn LogisticRegression
# # one unit increases of x increases the odd of (y) by .... 
print(np.exp(model_logistic.coef_))
#sm.Logit
print(np.exp(model_logit.params))```




Ok so you’ve fixed the perfect separation issue, but it remains the case that Sklearn applies L2 regularization by default (for reasons known only to god).

So GLM and logit are still not identical under the umbrella of statsmodel.  For the Sklearn, penalty=None, is not working. Here is what i got ValueError: Unsupported set of arguments: The combination of penalty='None' and loss='logistic_regression' is not supported, Parameters: penalty=None, loss='logistic_regression', dual=False

Sounds like a programming problem. Not on topic.

How about the difference encountered between the GLM (with sm.families.Binomial(link=sm.families.links.Logit()) and logit functions?

quick check model_logit.summary() is missing the intercept. model_logit = sm.Logit(y,x).fit() does not use x_with_ones. Logit and GLM-Logit produce identical results in well posed cases. (different behavior is possible in ill-defined cases like perfect collinearity or separation, or programming mistakes by user)

You are right. I thought the Logit function did not take a column of ones like LogisticRegression. Now, GLM and Logit are almost identical.

I uploaded the new figure.
